# F# FSharp.Data.SqlClient not recognizing multiple return tables from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, f#, f#-data

I am not sure if this is possible but I have not been able to come across clear documentation for this use case. I am using F# 4 and the `FSharp.Data.SqlClient` library to connect to SQL Server 2016. I am wanting to call a stored procedure that returns multiple tables and turn those tables into the corresponding records. In this case the first table is made up of `items` and the second table is made up of `customers`.

My instinct is that it should look something like this:

```
let items, customers = cmd.Execute()
```

My gut is that `items` would be an `IEnumerable<item>` and `customers` would be an `IEnumerable<customer>` where `item` and `customer` are both Record types. What it appears is happening though is that `FSharp.Data.SqlClient` is only seeing the first returned table from the stored procedure. I am working on a SQL Server 2016 Developer instance. Here is the T-SQL to setup the example:

```
create table Item (
    ItemID int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    ItemName nvarchar(50)
)
go

create table Customer (
    CustomerID int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    CustomerName nvarchar(50)
)
go

insert into Item (ItemName) values ('A');
insert into Item (ItemName) values ('B');
insert into Item (ItemName) values ('C');

insert into Customer (CustomerName) values ('Gary');
insert into Customer (CustomerName) values ('Sergei');
insert into Customer (CustomerName) values ('Elise');
go

create procedure dbo.ExampleProcedure
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    select
        ItemID,
        ItemName
    from Item

    select
        CustomerID,
        CustomerName
    from Customer

end;
```

And here is the F# script that I am testing with. It shows what I would like to be able to do but I get a compile error on the last line:

```
#r "../packages/FSharp.Data.SqlClient.1.8.2/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.SqlClient.dll"
#r "../packages/FSharp.Data.2.3.2/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"
open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let connStr = 
    "Data Source=**connection string**;"

type queryExample = SqlProgrammabilityProvider<connStr>
do
    use cmd = new queryExample.dbo.ExampleProcedure(connStr)
    let items, customers = cmd.Execute()
```

I am wanting `items` to correspond to the first returned table and `customers` to correspond to the second returned table. The intellisense suggests that FSharp.Data.SqlClient is only seeing the first table. When I hover over `cmd.Execute()` the popup says `"This expression was expected to have type 'a*'b but here has type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SqlProgrammabilityProvider<...>.dbo.ExampleProcedure.Record>"`. If I do the following I get access to the `Items` query in the stored procedure:

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.org. See the 'F# Tutorial' project
// for more guidance on F# programming.
#r "../packages/FSharp.Data.SqlClient.1.8.2/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.SqlClient.dll"
#r "../packages/FSharp.Data.2.3.2/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"
open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let connStr = 
    "Data Source=**connection string**;"

type queryExample = SqlProgrammabilityProvider<connStr>
do
    use cmd = new queryExample.dbo.ExampleProcedure(connStr)
    for item in cmd.Execute() do
        printfn "%A" item.ItemID
```

Is this even possible? Is my approach wrong? I could not find clear documentation on this use case but I thought it would be common enough it would be covered.

### Update

Just to clarify what I am trying to achieve I am showing how I solve this in C#. In C# I create a `DataSet` object and populate it with the results of the Stored Procedure. From there I pick out the individual tables to work with. After extracting the tables I then use LINQ to transform the rows into the corresponding objects. It often looks something like the following:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

var connStr = "**connection string**"
var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connStr );
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("ExampleProcedure", sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
var dataSet = new DataSet();
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
var itemsTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
// Turn the itemsTable into a List<Item> using LINQ here
var customersTable = dataSet.Tables[1];
// Turn the customersTable into List<Customer> using LINQ here
```

I find this to be overly verbose for such a simple thing as extracting the individual tables but perhaps I am too sensitive to code clutter. I know that F# must have a more elegant and terse way to express this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know F#, however this is a data access problem.

When a stored procedure returns multiple resultsets, you need to access they in sequence, one by one.

cmd.ExecuteReader() returns an instance of a datareader pointing to the first resultset. You need to process this resultset, may be filling a list with instances of a custom class, than you call the method "NextResult" and you will have access to the next resultset and so on.

A reference for the method "NextResult": https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx